# "undefined" on line 0

Tags: css, magento

I have a Magento controller with a block and a template. It's supposed to act as a dynamic style sheet with dependencies on store number etc.

When I view it in the browser it looks good:

http://www.example.com/module/css/

```
line 1: body { color: #6e6e6d; }
line 2: a, #vert-nav li.active a.level-top, .regular-price .price { color: #0076cf; }
line 3: body { background-color: #696969; }
...
```

But when I include it in the head of the intended document Magento curiously prints "undefined" at line 0 of the file:

link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/module/css/" type="text/css" media="all"

```
line -1:
line 0: undefined
line 1: body { color: #6e6e6d; }
line 2: a, #vert-nav li.active a.level-top, .regular-price .price { color: #0076cf; }
line 3: body { background-color: #696969; }
...
```

Also, the file is not recognised as "text/css" by the browser even though I set the header type correctly. My guess is that the "undefined" is echoed before I set the header type (that would cause it to fail right?).

I don't have a lot of experience with Magento so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/module/css/" type="text/css" media="all"` Youre linking to a folder rather than a CSS file. This shouldn't work. Try linking to the style sheet directly.

Comment: Thanks guys. I solved it myself. Turns out I didn't set the header type correctly after all and the "undefined" was something that Chrome writes in the file for some reason.

Comment: @Alex, in Magento that is how you access controllers. It's not really a directory as the server parses the relative path as a set of paramters. Anyway, it's woking now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didn't set the header type correctly after all. The right way to do it is this:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader("Content-Type", "text/css");
```

if anyone was wondering.

The "undefined" thing is a not so helpful hint from Chrome that your header type is wrong.